# Facebook API share a Facebook Video in post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm trying to post on a users' wall through the Facebook Opengraph API and the PHP SDK.

All is working fine - except the video I'm attempting to include in the post (hosted on Facebook videos) is failing to show up on the wall/timeline of the user being posted to.

I'm setting the URL to the video as the 'source' value in the $attachment data sent to /me/feed. Also setting 'type' to video.
On the wall I get a placeholder thumbnail and the rest of the post as specified.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to link to the video as a link. For other types of shared content, you should check out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/. Let me know if this isn't what you were trying to do.

Comment: Hi, yes it does work when the link is set to the video. What I was hoping to achieve was attach a video to the post, but link to the application that the video was shared through. Haven't found a way to make this work though sadly :(

Comment: You mean, clicking the video should link to the app, or?